# How do I prompt for user input in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, plugins, input

I'm writing a Maven plugin which I'd like to prompt for a simple user input and decide whether to halt the plugin's execution.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
$> mvn myplugin:run

[MAVEN] would you like to continue? [default value: y] _
```

I've tried using maven-antrun-plugin as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340894/is-there-a-way-to-capture-user-input-in-maven-and-assign-it-to-a-maven-propertty), but in this case Maven gets user input when I build my plugin. Instead, I'd like to retrieve input when user is running my plugin from within some other app that has declared my plugin (confusing?)

Comment: And how would you address automated builders like TravisCI that need to use your plugin?

Comment: I have the same requirement. Trying to inject a Prompter into my Mojo but no joy yet

Comment: I ended up giving up on user input. Instead, I print messages informing user if something unusual happens.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [Prompter](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-components/plexus-interactivity/plexus-interactivity-api/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/components/interactivity/Prompter.html) component and have it injected in your plugin (assuming you are using [Maven plugin annotations](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html), if not use the [equivalent javadoc tags](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html#The_Descriptor_and_Annotations)):

```
@Component
private Prompter prompter;
```

And to use it:

```
String name = prompter.prompt("Please enter your name");
```

Pull in this dependency in your plugin's POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
    <artifactId>plexus-interactivity-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-6</version>
</dependency>
```

The prompter component is used by the release plugin for prompting the user for tags and versions and the archetype plugin as well.

Comment: Source code moved: [Prompter](https://github.com/sonatype/plexus-interactivity/blob/master/plexus-interactivity-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/components/interactivity/Prompter.java)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.  If you need to supply data to a mojo, do it via configuration.

The behavior of your Maven build should be entirely predictable based on your POM and the goals & options supplied to the Maven command line.  If you allow a user to feed in additional information during the build, your POM no longer completely describes your project.

Also, it would prevent any automated build server doing its job.

Comment: This plugin I'm developing is not really supposed to be run by an automated tool. Its purpose is to perform some configurations on a given project. All I want to do is warn the user that these modifications are going to happen and ask for his confirmation, pretty much like a JavaScript confirm() message, or something like that. But I think I get your point. A maven plugin is supposed to be attached to a maven phase, therefore, will always be executed when the project is automatically built, it's not like a Grails script, which is invoked by user on command line, but not via a build tool.

Answer (score 0):

as variant, to not break maven way as wool.in.silver wrote, you can use shell script that will prompt values and then call maven with gathered values as parameters