# How to do input task in maven antrun plugin

Tags: maven, input, release, maven-antrun-plugin, external-script

I created a maven project and i'm trying to run an external script.
In this external script, i use read command to ask a question and get an answer.

It works if i do a **sudo mvn package** with [exec-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)

But, but, but :

- If i do a **sudo mvn package**, my script doesn't stop at read command.
- If i do a **sudo mvn release:prepare** with exec-maven-plugin, my script doesn't stop at read command.
- If i do a **sudo mvn release:prepare** with maven-antrun-plugin, my script doesn't stop at read command.

And obviously, i need to do a release :)

I tried to to change the first line of my script (#/usr/bin/bash, sh, ...) with other syntaxes for read command...

Is anyone have a solution to help me ???

Here the concerned part of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>initialisation</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
        <exec dir="${project.basedir}" executable="${project.basedir}/livraison/outils/0_init_livraison.ksh" failonerror="true">
          <arg line="${project.name} ${project.version} ${ancienneVersion}" />
        </exec>
       </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here the concerned part of my 0_init_livraison.ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo -e "| EXECUTION DU SCIPT generation_livrable.ksh \n"

echo "SHELL : $SHELL"
boucle="boucler"
while [ $boucle -eq "boucler" ]
do
    echo -ne "  Souhaitez-vous forcer la procedure (oui/non)? "
    read rep1

    case "$rep1" in
    o|O|y|Y|oui|Oui|OUI|yes|Yes|YES)
    echo ""
    break
    ;;

    n|N|non|Non|NON|no|No|NO)
    echo -e "  Abandon de la procedure..."
    boucle=""
    exit 1
    ;;
    *) 
    echo -e "  Reponse incomprehensible.\c"
    esac
done
```

The last lines of my console when i do a sudo mvn package ( And then, nothing happens. It seems blocked because of an infinite while loop)

```
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (initialisation) @ MyProject---
[WARNING] Parameter tasks is deprecated, use target instead
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
   [exec] | EXECUTION DU SCIPT generation_livrable.ksh
   [exec]
   [exec] SHELL : /bin/bash
```

Thanks for the reading :)

**EDIT :**

I tried to use  property with maven-antrun-plugin.
But i have a similar problem: [antrun input task doesn't work during mvn release:prepare operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981482/antrun-input-task-doesnt-work-during-mvn-releaseprepare-operation)

Comment: Where is variable `$boucle` defined in your script?

Comment: I miss it during the copy/paste. I edited the post

Comment: I suggest you read user input through the `input` Ant task. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340894/is-there-a-way-to-capture-user-input-in-maven-and-assign-it-to-a-maven-propertty) for more info.

Comment: I tried to use <input> task. A similar problem appears : input task appears to be blocked during release prepare operation (I edited my post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use Exec ksh instead of script name with a script as a parameterthose but it didn't work.
I tried to set ANT_HOME variable but it didn't work.

**But i changed my way of thinking** :
Having a build that depends on the console is extremely problematic, most integration tools around Maven will not work with it because they assume autonomous runs. This kind of maven project would encounter problems with Jenkins , Netbeans,... They cannot wait for manual answer.

The best way is to set an option and run a command with a parameter :

**mvn clean packge -Dforcer=oui** or **mvn release:prepare -Darguments=-Dforcer=oui**

Here a part of my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>initialisation</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <exec executable="${outilsLivraison}/0_init_livraison.ksh" failonerror="false" resultproperty="codeRetour">
            <redirector errorproperty="message.redirector.err" />
          </exec>
          <fail message=" ARRET DE LA PROCEDURE ! VOUS POUVEZ FORCER LA PROCEDURE AVEC '-Dforcer=oui' (ou '-Darguments=-Dforcer=oui' pour une release).">
            <condition>
              <and>
                <equals arg1="${message.redirector.err}" arg2="warning" />
                <not><equals arg1="${forcer}" arg2="oui" /></not>
              </and>
            </condition>
          </fail>
          <fail message=" Erreur">
            <condition>
              <equals arg1="${codeRetour}" arg2="1" />
            </condition>
          </fail>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here a function which is called in my 0_init_livraison.ksh script when a problem is detected :

```
fonc_warning(){
  echo "warning" 1>&2
}
```

So my problem is solved.

Anyway, thank's for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

EITHER

Set environment variable ANT_HOME, add a property to you Maven:
`<property name="ant.home" value="${env.ANT_HOME}" />` and add a parameter `vmlauncher="true"` to your Ant Exec part.

OR

Exec `ksh` instead of script name with a script as a parameter. I mean:

```
<exec dir="${project.basedir}" executable="ksh" failonerror="true">
<arg value="${project.basedir}/livraison/outils/0_init_livraison.ksh">
</exec>
```