# antrun input task doesn't work during mvn release:prepare operation

Tags: maven, input, release, maven-antrun-plugin

I try to use  property with maven-antrun-plugin.
But it seems to be blocked in some case (I had the [similar problem with exec-maven-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31945237/how-to-do-input-task-in-maven-antrun-plugin) :

- It work with **sudo mvn package** : The script 0_init_livraison.ksh is executed. After this, execution, antrun asked me a question "Souhaitez-vous continuer ?" If the answer is yes, the build can continue. If the answer is no the script send an error message and the build is stopped.
- It don't work with **sudo mvn release:prepare** : antrun ask the question and the build stay blocked (regardless of my answer)

I need to do a release

Here the concerned part of my pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>initialisation</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <configuration>
        <tasks>
          <exec dir="${project.basedir}"
            executable="${project.basedir}/livraison/outils/0_init_livraison.ksh"
            failonerror="false"
            resultproperty="sortieInitScript">
            <arg line="${project.name} ${project.version} ${ancienneVersion}" />
            <redirector errorproperty="redirector.err" />
          </exec>
          <echo message="Resultat ${sortieInitScript}, Message ${redirector.err}"/>
          <input message="  Souhaitez-vous Continuer ? "
            validargs="o,n"
            addproperty="procedureChoix" />
          <fail message="ARRET VOLONTAIRE DE LA PROCEDURE !!">
            <condition>
              <equals arg1="${procedureChoix}" arg2="n" />
            </condition>
          </fail>
        </tasks>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here the concerned part of my 0_init_livraison.ksh :

```
 ...
echo -e "\n| FIN DU SCIPT "
echo -e " ============================================================"
echo "warning" 1>&2
```

The last lines of my console when i do a sudo mvn package :

```
[exec] | FIN DU SCIPT
[exec]  ============================================================
[exec]
[echo] Resultat 0, Message warning
Souhaitez-vous Continuer ?  (o, n)
o
[INFO] Executed tasks (<- this last line doesn't appear with mvn release:prepare. But it appears with mvn package)
 ...
```

Do i miss something with release command ?

Thanks for the reading :)

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot answer in the console"? Aren't you running both mvn commands with the same shell, environment, JVM, POM etc.? Is your antrun plugin actually executed?

Comment: Yes i'm running both command with the same user (sudo), environment, project, JVM.... Yes, antrun plugin is executed because the script (which is lanched by antrun) And i can read the question "Souhaitez-vous continuer ? on my console. But it stay blocked (regardless of my answer)