# How to trigger the execution of testng files after an input from the console

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

I am having different test suites in my pom.xml file.

I want to give user input from the console after running every testng suite file to trigger the execution of next testng file in the pom.xml.

Eg: my pom.xml file contains 3 testng files as below.
testng1.xml
testng2.xml
testng2.xml
after execution of testng1.xml file, the execution of testng2.xml should start only after I give the input(like any key press from keyboard).

How to acheive this in selenium webdriver(page object model), java, testng, maven framework.

Comment: here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340894/is-there-a-way-to-capture-user-input-in-maven-and-assign-it-to-a-maven-propertty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to this answer.

I used scanner object in the @Test of testng.xml file where ever i want the "wait until" user gives input from the console. In that case the execution of the tests waits until user gives the input to the console.

Example code.

```
@Test(priority=20)
public void testInputFromConsoleToContinue_XX1(){
    System.out.println("Click any key and 'enter' key in Console to continue the tests..");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("continue the tests " + line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

**pom.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>${file.name}</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

From command line you can run:

```
mvn test -Dfile.name=path of testng<i>.xml
```