# Can maven prompt for username and password

Tags: maven-3, prompt, password-protection

I am currently passing my password and username as arguments in maven command line. Is there any plugin available in maven to prompt for username and password while deploying to a server. I am using maven 3.3.9 version

Comment: You can use encrypted passwords in your settings.xml: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

Answer (score 0):

I heave serached for myself for a long time for something similar, but I see only two possible solutions:

1. Write a maven plugin for this
2. [Use Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494574/3021395) like explained in this similar stackoverflow answer